# Unable to Select A UITableView Row on Tap, But Can On Long Tap

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have an iOS App that has the following flow:

UITabView -> TabView with UITableView -> Select A Row -> UITabView (as full screen modal) -> UITabView with UIViewController and a UITableView

The UITableView Rows in the UIViewController don't allow me to select them on a single tap. I can select them if I either A) 2-Finger Tap or B) Long Press (3D Force Touch?) on the row. Then the row triggers the `didSelectRowAt`. Otherwise nothing happens.

I've tried setting these on the UITableView

```
self.catalogItemsTableView.allowsSelection = true
self.catalogItemsTableView.selectionFollowsFocus = true
self.catalogItemsTableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true
```

But they haven't changed anything. Here's what the View Looks like. Is it because the UITableView is inside of a full screen Modal? I'm loading the 'Modal' View with the following code:

```
let orderEntryViewController = OrderEntryViewController(order: order, parentVC: self.parentVC!)
orderEntryViewController.order = order
orderEntryViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                
self.parentVC!.present(orderEntryViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image: UITableView in Full Screen Modal]

Comment: “Is it because the UITableView is inside of a full screen Modal?” No. More likely you have done something to the cell or table that eats the tap.

Comment: @matt My hats off to you. I had a tap gesture for dismissing the keyboard and it was consuming the table view tap.

Comment: No problem! I've done the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I had this in the view that was consuming the table view tap. I put it in place to dismiss the keyboard

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIInputViewController.dismissKeyboard))

view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Removing this allowed the UITableView taps to work correctly again.

Answer (score 0):

You could also implement gesture recognizer delegate and then check wether the touch is on table view or not.

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    
    if touch.view?.isDescendantOfView(self.catalogItemsTableView) == true {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```